# Configure xxxParam Tags in Free jqGrid for reloading after inline-add

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm not able to find a description which tag belongs to which position - allways searching for comments from oleg ;-).

I've a table with actionbuttons (edit/del) in the row. Adding ist done over inlinenav add:true:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() 
 {
  currentCompanyCode = '<s:property value="currentCompanyCode" />';
  jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "serverAction"   ,
        pager: true,
        pgbuttons:false, pginput:false, pgtext:false,       
        datatype: "json", 
        mtype: "POST",   
       ajaxGridOptions: {async: false},

       aftersavefunc: function() {reloadGrid("grid")},
        postData: { currentCompanyCode : function () {return jQuery("#availCompanyCodes").val();}},
        pager:              '#addBtns',

        colModel:[
            {name:"id",                 label:"key", hidden:true, key:true},
            {name:"priority",           label:"prio"},
             ....
            {name: "act",               label:"", align: "left", template:"actions"}
        ],
        actionsNavOptions: {delbutton: true, editbutton: true}
        }


    }) .jqGrid("navGrid",   '#addBtns', {refresh:true, edit:false, del:false, search:false, add:false },
                                        {/*edit Options*/}, 
                                        {/*add Options*/},
                                        {/*del Options*/},
                                        {/*search Options*/})
      .jqGrid("inlineNav", '#addBtns',  {
          save:true, edit:false, add:true, 
          editParams: {keys: true, successfunc : function() {reloadGrid("grid")},   extraparam: {currentCompanyCode : function () {return jQuery("#availCompanyCodes").val()}}},
          addParams: {addRowParams:{successfunc : function() {reloadGrid("grid")},  extraparam:{ currentCompanyCode : function () {return jQuery("#availCompanyCodes").val()}}}}
        })
 });
```

This is an extract from our grid-definition. Took some time to figure out, how I can set postdata when inlinediting or addding. 
Two Questions:
Is there an easier way to add postdata in inlineediting? It looks complicated ;-)

The grid will not reload when I add a new line and press the save-icon in the actions-cell. It reloads when pressing Enter or the Savebutton in the pagerbar. Where should I put the reload-statement?

I don't understand why in edit-mode the successfunc-tag belongs to the editParams block, but in add-mode it has to be in the addRowParams block. Is there anywhere a description where to put these tags?
Thanx oleg - the grid is great, but sometimes I miss a documentation....

Comment: Could you specify which kind of additional information you want to sent during inline editing? There are many ways to implement your requirements and I don't describe all possibilities in my answer. :-) Do you want to send, for example, the data existing in the same row (non-editable data) or to send some values, which you get from DOM (like `currentCompanyCode` which you get from  `jQuery("#availCompanyCodes").val()`) or ... Is the usage of `extraparam` work, but you want to know alternatives?

Comment: @Oleg The additional postdata is in this case a select-box with the companycode - its a filter for the griddata and needs to part of every request - that works.  My main problem is the edit-button in the  actions-template  cell. I've to refresh the griddata from DB after adding a row. That works pressing Enter in the edited row or by clicking the savebutton  in  "inlineNav". It doesn't work with the savebutton in the actions-cell. I think I've to put another reload-trigger anywhere in the tags, but where?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, which you describe, is related to the common design of jqGrid. jqGrid provides not only the options used during creating the grid, but it has many other methods used directly or *indirectly*, which options need be specified.

For example, there are exist [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) method, which its set of options and callbacks. You want to specify `keys` and `extraparam` options and the `successfunc` callback. Direct call of `editRow` (inside of `onSelectRow` or `ondblClickRow` callbacks, for example) will look like

```
$(this).jqGrid("editRow", {
    keys: true,
    extraparam: { ... },
    successfunc: function() { ... }
});
```

The problem is that the `editRow` will be called not only directly, by *indirectly*, from [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow), from `inlineNav` or from the action formatter. Every from the methods provides some ways to specify the options, which will be forwarded to `editRow`, but the usage of such options is not comfortable and the maintain of resulting code isn't so good.

Because of that free jqGrid introduced the possibility to specify **default options for the grid context**. The grid parameter `inlineEditing` for example allow to specify default options of `editRow` on one place and all direct or indirect calls of `editRow` will uses the options. One can still overwrite the options is needed (inside of `editParams` option of `inlineNav`, for example). In the same way, one can use new jqGrid options `formEditing`, `formViewing`, `formDeleting`, `searching`, `navOptions`, `inlineNavOptions` and so on. Additionally some simple options like `pager` are improved in free jqGrid. One can specify `pager: true` and jqGrid will create the div for the pager itself, like it does for `toppager: true` option. One can just skip the pager parameter (`'#addBtns'` in your case) for `navGrid`, `inlineNav` or `navButtonAdd`. By the way, your original code contains syntax error: you use `pager` property of jqGrid *twice*: once as `pager: true` and once more as `pager: '#addBtns'`.

Thus you can rewrite your original code to for example the following

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "serverAction",
    datatype: "json", 
    mtype: "POST",   
    pager: true,
    pgbuttons: false,
    pginput: false,
    pgtext: false,       
    postData: {
        currentCompanyCode: function () {
            return jQuery("#availCompanyCodes").val();
        }
    },
    colModel:[
        //{name: "id",     label: "key", hidden: true, key: true},
        {name: "priority", label: "prio"},
         ....
        {name: "act",      label: "", align: "left", template: "actions"}
    ],
    navOptions: { edit: false, del: false, search: false, add: false },
    inlineNavOptions: { add: true, edit: true },
    actionsNavOptions: { delbutton: true, editbutton: true },
    inlineEditing: {
        keys: true,
        extraparam: {
            currentCompanyCode: function () {
                return jQuery("#availCompanyCodes").val();
            }
        },
        aftersavefunc: function () {
            var $grid = jQuery(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
            });
        }
    }
}) .jqGrid("navGrid")
  .jqGrid("inlineNav");
```